# Can I use branch of discriminated unions for specify record type 's members?

Tags: f#

How can I specify the type of member `FilterConditions` of `Query`, thus to limit its by `BoolExpr` of `Expr`?

```
type Expr =
    | BoolExpr of Expr
    | ConstValue of Object
    | FieldAccess of string

type Query = {
    SelectList: Expr list
    FilterConditions: Expr.BoolExpr list  // Expr.BoolExpr - this is don't valid? why?
}
```

I want restrict type of FilterConditions by only `BoolExpr` of `Expr`. Is it possible? Or I must re-design structure of AST?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of union type is to provide a uniform access to different types.
Knowing that, you have a few options depending on your analysis :

- If you really feel one case has a life on its own, you can create a type for it and wrap it in the union case
- You could pattern match in the function that uses the Query type, and use the uniform Expr type for the parameters. in that case it seems like the good thing to do.